# "int cannot be dereferenced" in some calculation methods

Tags: java, swing

so, I had spent a while writing some calculation methods to get some import numbers in a preview battle window in an rpg i'm trying out to make(anyone remember fire emblem? it's sort of a simplified version of that).
here is where I try to form a jtable from these c

```
public static JTable getBattleDataTable(RPGChar attacker, RPGChar defender){
        String[] top={attacker.getCharacterName(), "", defender.getCharacterName()};
        String[][] battledata=new String[3][3];
        battledata[0][0]="Health";
        battledata[0][1]=attacker.getHealth();
        battledata[0][2]=defender.getHealth();

        battledata[1][0]="Hit Chance";
        battledata[1][1]=calculateChanceofHitting(attacker, defender).toString();
        battledata[1][2]=calculateChanceofHitting(defender, attacker).toString();

        battledata[2][0]="Damage";
        battledata[2][1]=calculatePotentialDamage(attacker, defender).toString();
        battledata[2][2]=calculatePotentialDamage(defender, attacker).toString();
        JTable battletable=new JTable(battledata, top);
        return battletable;
    }​
```

alculation methods(calculateChanceofHitting and calculatePotentialDamage, which both return ints). as you can see from the string array and toStrings(), I want the int return types to be changed to strings, then inserted to the array. but it is giving a "int cannot be dereferenced" error when I try to compile... anyone know something that can help? it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since `calculateChanceOfHitting` and `calculatePotentialDamage` both return `int` values, attempting to invoke a method on them is illegal. Instead of using the `toString` method, you can try [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-):

```
battledata[1][1] = String.valueOf(calculateChanceofHitting(attacker, defender));
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the code where the problem is, but that error means you're trying to call a method on a primitive.